# I am trying to make screen manager open different screens first depending on a variable time Kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

Is there any way to change which screen your screenmmanager starts on in kivy. My screen manager is on a kivy file in kivy language, but my App class is obviously in python which is where I am putting the function the check which screen the screen manager should start on.

It should look a little like this:

kvfile.kv

```
<Screenmanager>
     Screen1:
          name: 'screen_1'
     Screen2:
          name: 'screen_2'
```

pythonfile.py

```
import "libraries"

class Screen1(Screen):
       pass

class Screen2(Screen):
       pass

class Screenmanager(ScreenManager):
       pass

class MyApp(self, App):
       def Build(self):
           if "I already have this code":
                  self.idk.idk.current = 'screen_1' <---- Here is where I need help
                  return Screenmanager
           else:
               self.idk.idk.current = 'screen_2' <------ And here obviously
               return Screenmanager
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just set `current` Screen before returning the `ScreenManager`. Something like:

```
class MyApp(self, App):
    def Build(self):
        Builder.load_file("kvfile.kv")
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.transition = NoTransition()
        if something:
            sm.current = "screen_1"
        else:
            sm.current = "screen_2"
        return sm
```

Comment: Yes, but my screen manager is defined in the kivy file and not in the python file, so how do I do that .current inside the kivy file.

Comment: I assumed that somewhere you were loading that `kv` file. I have modified my answer to include that loading.